Bias of a ratio estimator
I am reading the book Sampling and Design Analysis
In chapter 4, page 128 there is computation of the bias of the ratio mean estimator which I have hard time understanding

Specifically why does
$$\ -E[\hat B (\bar x - \bar x_u)] = - Cov(\hat B, \bar x) $$

Hint: $E(\bar x)=\bar x_U$. (Is this homework?)

Kind of. I will need to present this subject. Do you mean $ E[\hat B(\bar x - \bar x_u)] = E[\hat B \bar x - \hat B \bar x_u] = E[\hat B \bar x] - E[\hat B]\bar x_u = E[\hat B \bar x] - E[\hat B]E[\bar x] = Cov(\hat B, \bar x)$

Yes, that's what I meant.
